# Compare command line arguments to string in C?

Tags: c

Compare command line arguments to strings in c?
for example I want just the word "autoplay" to be the command line argument, how can i validate that this is the only word? i already have it validating for more than 1 word.

```
if( argc == 2 ) {
    autoplay(num5);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing special about command line arguments, they're just ordinary strings. Use `strcmp()` to compare them. `if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "autoplay") == 0)`

Comment: How about something like `for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) if(strcmp(argv[i], "autoplay") == 0) autoplay(num5);`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits `strcmp()` doesn't return a boolean, it returns `0` when the strings match.

Comment: @Barmar That was a typo.

Comment: `if( argc == 2 )` then there only is one argument. If can therefor only be the only word. So, either your question needs more explanation, or it is already solved by the code you have shown.

Answer (score 2):

You use `strcmp()` to compare strings; note it returns 0 on match.  If you want it case insensitive then you need to use `strcasecmp()` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(argc == 2 && !strcmp(argv[1], "autoplay")) {
        printf("match\n");
        // autoplay(num5);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("no match\n");
}
```

and example run;

```
./a.out
no match
./a.out autoplay
match
```